# Create custom pagination

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, dynamic-html

Hey guys am working on a quote website. And am new to JavaScript. I have returned some quotes.

### My JavaScript

```js
const status = [
  { status: "Do what is right not what is easy." },
  { status: "Hey there, WhatsApp is using me."},
  { status: "Too Busy" },
  { status: "Only you can give me that feeling." },
  { status: "I had a horribly busy day in converting oxygen into carbon dioxide" },
  { status: "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken" },
  { status: "Your attitude may hurt me, But main can Kill You!!"},
  { status: "Love is Blind, be careful." },
  { status: "'SUCCESS' is depend on U." },
  { status: "If you love someone set it free." },
  { status: "Love is sweet, When it's new. But it is sweeter when it's true." },
  { status: "Where there is love, there is life." },
  { status: "Not always 'Available' try your luck.." },
  { status: "I am not changed it's just I grew up and you should try too." },
  { status: "The biggest slap to your enemies is your success." },
  { status: "Born to express, not to impress."},
];
```

I have used the word "status" just for my sake. I wanted a custom pagination, so that a single page should contain only 5 quotes.

Although my friend gave me JavaScript but it's too difficult to understand (for me!!). So if any one can find any error, any extra code or any different JavaScript please help.

### Friend's JavaScript

```js
$(function() {
//(function(name) {
//  var container = $('#pagination-' + name);
//  var sources = function() {
//    var result = [];
//    for (var i = 1; i < 196; i++) {
//      result.push(i);
//    }
//    return result;
//  }();
//  console.log(sources)
//  var options = {
//    dataSource: sources,
//    callback: function(response, pagination) {
//      window.console && console.log(response, pagination);
//      var dataHtml = '<ul>';
//      $.each(response, function(index, item) {
//        dataHtml += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
//      });
//      dataHtml += '</ul>';
//      container.prev().html(dataHtml);
//    }
//  };
//  $.pagination(container, options);
//  container.addHook('beforeInit', function() {
//    window.console && console.log('beforeInit...');
//  });
//  container.pagination(options);
//  container.addHook('beforePageOnClick', function() {
//    window.console && console.log('beforePageOnClick...');
//    return false
//  });
//})('demo1');
  (function(name) {
    var container = $('#pagination-' + name);
    container.pagination({
      dataSource: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=cat&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
      locator: 'items',
      totalNumber: 50,
      pageSize: 2,
      showPageNumbers: true,
      showPrevious: true,
      showNext: true,
      showNavigator: true,
      showFirstOnEllipsisShow: true,
      showLastOnEllipsisShow: true,
      ajax: {
        beforeSend: function() {
          container.prev().html('Loading data from flickr.com ...');
        }
      },
      callback: function(response, pagination) {
        window.console && console.log(22, response, pagination);
        var dataHtml = '<ul>';
        $.each(response, function(index, item) {
          dataHtml += '<li>' + item.title + '</li>';
        });
        dataHtml += '</ul>';
        container.prev().html(dataHtml);
      }
    })
  })('demo2');
})
```

Any one who are experts in JavaScript please can you make this javascript so dynamic that the each quote should create itself a `<div><p></p></div>` and paste in it.

### My HTML

```html
<div class="allStatus">
  <div class="latestatus">
    <p class="copytxt"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I needed the quotes to placed in:

```html
<div class="latestatus"><p class="copytxt"></p></div>
```

And thanks for those who answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order to page in JavaScript, your data will have to come back with paging information, or you will have to store the full result locally and re-render based on the inputs of the user.

Here is an example of a local transformation function:

```js
const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));
```

### Full example

```js
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.pagable-results');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

let results = [];

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async () => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageCurr.addEventListener('change', navCustom);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);
  
  retrieveAllStatuses().then(response => {
    results = response; // Store globally, or in a scope...
    updatePager();
    redraw();
  });
};

const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');
  paged.forEach(record => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = record.status;
    ul.append(li);
  });
  resultEl.append(ul);
};

const navFirst = (e) => {
  updateCurrPage(1);
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  updateCurrPage(reboundPage(getCurrPage() - 1));
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  updateCurrPage(reboundPage(getCurrPage() + 1));
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  updateCurrPage(getPageCount());
  redraw();
}

const navCustom = (e) => {
  updateCurrPage(reboundPage(getCurrPage()));
  updatePager();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = (e) => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updateCurrPage = (page) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = page;
  pageCurr.value = page;
}

const reboundPage = (page) =>
  (pageCount => page < 1 ? 1 : page > pageCount ? pageCount : page)
  (getPageCount())

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllStatuses = () => Promise.resolve([
  { status: "Do what is right not what is easy." },
  { status: "Hey there, WhatsApp is using me."},
  { status: "Too Busy" },
  { status: "Only you can give me that feeling." },
  { status: "I had a horribly busy day in converting oxygen into carbon dioxide" },
  { status: "Be yourself; everyone else is already taken" },
  { status: "Your attitude may hurt me, But main can Kill You!!"},
  { status: "Love is Blind, be careful." },
  { status: "'SUCCESS' is depend on U." },
  { status: "If you love someone set it free." },
  { status: "Love is sweet, When it's new. But it is sweeter when it's true." },
  { status: "Where there is love, there is life." },
  { status: "Not always 'Available' try your luck.." },
  { status: "I am not changed it's just I grew up and you should try too." },
  { status: "The biggest slap to your enemies is your success." },
  { status: "Born to express, not to impress."},
]);

main();
```

```css
:root {
  --pageable-background: inherit;
  --pageable-border: thin solid grey;
  --pageable-status-background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

ul li {
  font-style: italic;
}

.pagable-results ul li:before,
.pagable-results ul li:after { content: "\""; }

.pagable {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagable" style="min-height:160px;">
  <div class="pagable-results"></div>
  <div class="pagable-status">
    <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
    <div class="pagable-actions">
      <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
      <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
      <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
      <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
      <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
      <select name="page-size">
        <option>5</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
  </div>
</div>
```